# Write a program that loads integer variables that have values ​0 or 1 and then tells if the expression is true or false

Tags: c

I just started programming and I have the following task: Write a program that loads integer variables that have values ​​0 or 1 and then tells if `(!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c` is true or false. I wrote this:

```
int a, b, c;
printf ("a: \n");
scanf ("%d", &a);
printf ("b: \n");
scanf ("%d", &b);
printf ("c: \n");
scanf ("%d", &c);

if ((a==1 || a==0) && (b==1 || b==0) && (c==0 || c==1))
    printf ("%d &&(%d||%d) || %d&&%d=%d\n", a, b, c, b &&(a||c) || a&&c );
else
    printf ("Numbers are not correct!\n");
```

I simplified the expression from the beginning and I got: `b(a+c)+a*c`. When I run this program, the output is not as expected; it is not 0 or 1 even though I take for example a=0, b=1, c=1 (which is what should work according to task, but the output is 4327). Can somebody help me? I use C.

Comment: `"%d &&(%d||%d) || %d&&%d=%d\n"` has 6 `"%d"` yet only 4 following `int` arguments.  Mia09, What is your intent here?

Comment: "is not working correctly." is vague.  Post example input, output seen and output expected.

Comment: I tried to wrote a formula to solve  that expression. So you say I must correct only that line?

Comment: Please read @chux-ReinstateMonica comment again. Please provide exact input, expected output ("1 or 0" is not the exact output for a given input) and actual output.

Comment: Your original boolean expression is symmetric; your deduced simplified expression is not symmetric.  That strongly suggests that one of the problems is in your simplification.

Comment: Does `not a*b*c` mean `!(a&b&c)` or `(!a)&b&c`? Etc.

Comment: I suggested that the simplification was wrong, but it isn't. The original expression is true if any two of `a`, `b`, `c` are true, or if all three are true.  On further scrutiny, the alternative does the same — but it could equivalently be written `c(a+b) + a*b` or `a(b+c) + b*c`; all should produce the same output.  The primary problem is your `printf()` statement, as pointed out by @chux in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130417/write-a-program-that-loads-integer-variables-that-have-values-0-or-1-and-then-t#comment104488848_59130417).  When you fix that, you should be OK.

Comment: This kind of expression:  `(a==1 || a==0)`  says if a is 0 or a is 1.   Since the only valid values for `a` are 0 and 1,  That expression will always be true.   Therefore, the `if` reduces to `if true and true and true`  or is this `if` trying to verify that the read values are valid?

Comment: regarding: `(!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c`  is the `&` to mean AND?  is the `!` to mean NOT?  is the `+` to mean ADD?

Comment: Per the question, the result is to be "true" or "false", however nothing in the posted code ever outputs those strings

Comment: Please clarify the syntax for the expression.  I.E.  what does `!` do, what does `&` do, what does `+` do?

Comment: @user3629249 That if needs to verify that the read values are valid (0 or 1) and if they are then it must calculate given expression and say if it is true (1) or false (0). ! is a symbol for logical not, & is logical and, and + is logical or.

Comment: @user3629249: No — users are notorious for not entering what they're told to enter.  The code necessarily checks that the user did enter 0 or 1 for each value (though the code should also check that the `scanf()` calls were successful).  If the user is neither careless nor nefarious, then the test condition will be true.  However, if the user is careless or nefarious, the condition could easily be false.  There might be better ways of doing the checking and error reporting (can anyone say "function"?), but the test is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `printf()` format string has 6 `%d` conversion specifications, but you only pass 4 values (`a`, `b`, `c` and the expression).  You either need to use the POSIX *`n$`* notation (see [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("a: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("b: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("c: \n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    if ((a == 1 || a == 0) && (b == 1 || b == 0) && (c == 0 || c == 1))
        printf("a = %1$d, b = %2$d, c = %3$d:  (%2$d && (%1$d || %3$d)) || (%1$d && %3$d) = %4$d\n",
               a, b, c, (b && (a || c)) || (a && c));
    else
        printf("Numbers are not correct!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

or you need to repeat the arguments as required:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c;
    printf("a: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("b: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("c: \n");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    if ((a == 1 || a == 0) && (b == 1 || b == 0) && (c == 0 || c == 1))
        printf("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d:  (%d && (%d || %d)) || (%d && %d) = %d\n",
               a, b, c, b, a, c, a, c, (b && (a || c)) || (a && c));
    else
        printf("Numbers are not correct!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output from both programs is the same.  I used a shell script to test `b41` (created from `b41.c`) like this:

```
for a in 0 1
do
    for b in 0 1
    do
        for c in 0 1
        do
            echo $a $b $c | b41
        done
    done
done | grep -v '^[abc]:'
```

The `grep` removes the prompt lines (they're boring!) and the output is:

```
a = 0, b = 0, c = 0:  (0 && (0 || 0)) || (0 && 0) = 0
a = 0, b = 0, c = 1:  (0 && (0 || 1)) || (0 && 1) = 0
a = 0, b = 1, c = 0:  (1 && (0 || 0)) || (0 && 0) = 0
a = 0, b = 1, c = 1:  (1 && (0 || 1)) || (0 && 1) = 1
a = 1, b = 0, c = 0:  (0 && (1 || 0)) || (1 && 0) = 0
a = 1, b = 0, c = 1:  (0 && (1 || 1)) || (1 && 1) = 1
a = 1, b = 1, c = 0:  (1 && (1 || 0)) || (1 && 0) = 1
a = 1, b = 1, c = 1:  (1 && (1 || 1)) || (1 && 1) = 1
```

Note that GCC set fussy recommended extra parentheses in the expression mixing `&&` and `||` operators.  It's good to know the precedence rules; it's better to write code to avoid making those reading the code have to remember the rules.

The original expression (`(!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c`) is symmetric in `a`, `b`, `c`, yet the revision is not, and I suggested that the simplification was wrong, but it isn't. The original expression is true if any two of `a`, `b`, `c` are true, or if all three are true. On further scrutiny, the alternative (`b(a+c) + a*c`) does the same — but it could equivalently be written `c(a+b) + a*b` or `a(b+c) + b*c`; all three should produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

> but the output is 4327

`printf()` lacks matching each `"%d"` with an `int` argument.  Result: *undefined behavior* (UB): anything may happen including garbage output.

```
//       1     2   3      4   5  6      1  2  3  v-----4----------v  (missing  5 and 6)
printf ("%d &&(%d||%d) || %d&&%d=%d\n", a, b, c, b &&(a||c) || a&&c );
```

Instead:

```
// For clarity, do one at a time.
{
printf("a:%d\n", a);
printf("b:%d\n", b);
printf("c:%d\n", b);
printf("Formula: %s\n", "(!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c");
printf("Formula result: %d\n", (!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality, using a table as input
3. displays the results of the logic equation

and now the proposed code:

```
 // the equation to solve
 //  if (!a)&b&c + a&(!b)&c + a&b&(!c) + a&b&c
 // where: `!` is a symbol for logical not, `&` is logical and, and `+` is logical or.

 #include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
     int a;
     int b;
     int c;

    #if 0 
     a = getchar();
     getchar();
     b = getchar();
     getchar();
     c = getchar();
    #endif

    int data[][3] =
    {
        { 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1 },
    };

    for( size_t i=0; i< sizeof( data ) / sizeof( data[0] ); i++ )
    {
        a = data[i][0];
        b = data[i][1];
        c = data[i][2];

        printf( "a=%d; b=%d: c=%d:\n", a, b, c);

        if ( (!a && b && c)   ||  (a && b && !c)  || (a && b && c) )
        {
            puts( "true\n" );
        }

        else
        {
            puts( "false\n" );
        }

    }
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
a=0; b=0: c=0:
false

a=0; b=0: c=1:
false

a=0; b=1: c=0:
false

a=0; b=1: c=1:
true

a=1; b=0: c=0:
false

a=1; b=0: c=1:
false

a=1; b=1: c=0:
true

a=1; b=1: c=1:
true
```

Comment: The long-hand condition doesn't match the one in the question, so the program outputs 'false' for `a = 1; b = 0; c = 1` when it should output 'true'.  The missing term is `|| (a && !b && c)`.

Comment: OOPS, I missed one of the logic groups,  The purpose of the answer is to show how to write the code.  Notice I did not include the verification of the values (0,1) either.  However, this should point the OP (who seems to be a student and this is a homework assignment) in the right direction without giving away everything